# Problem congifuring Nginx to visualize Swagger UI

Tags: nginx, swagger-ui

I have a containerized dotnet service including swagger UI that I can locally run on `localhost:7060/swagger/index.html`.

I have a problem configuring nginx to point to it. Here is my weaplan.conf file that nginx detects

```
server {
    Listen 80;
    location /swagger {
         root /var/www/html/weaplanservices/DataHandlerAPI;
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7060;
         try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }    
}
```

Note: the project exists in the exact indicated root and the containerized app works correctly

Comment: Can you specify what is the problem? do you receive an error code?

Comment: You don't need `root` and `try_files` if you use `proxy_pass` - remove the `proxy_pass` and put the `index.html` inside `/var/www/html/weaplanservices/DataHandlerAPI` folder. Don't forget to restart nginX.

Comment: I deleted them and received a blank page. The app is running swagger UI that works locally with docker via `localhost:7060/swagger/index.html`. When deploying I also launched the app and received a blank page in return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by reconfiguring nginx this way to serve Swagger UI:

```
    server {
        Listen 80;
        location /swagger {
        root /var/www/html/weaplanservices/DataHandlerAPI;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7060;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
```